# How to make users not be logged out after certain time (PHP/APACHE)

Tags: php, apache

I already made these adjustments in my php.in file and then stopped/started the server:

```
; 24 hour session cookie
session.cookie_lifetime = 86400

; Prevent server from cleaning up session
; Some value higher than the cookie lifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 200000
```

But that seemed to do nothing and my users are still complaining that they get logged out after about 30 minutes.  And I am also getting logged out often.

What else could I look into or do in order to make my users who are logged in not to be logged out and keep them logged in at least 24 hours or more.

Thanks!

Comment: @genadinik if you call die(in_get("session.cookie_lifetime")); in your code, what does it print out?

Comment: @Geoffrey actually that gave this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function in_get() - not sure what it means :)

Comment: @genadinik sorry it should be die(ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime"));

Comment: @Geoffrey actually the die() part made this not work.  Without the die function, I got this: Session time: 7200

Comment: @genadinik Then your php.ini vars are not carrying into your application, otherwise part of your application is changing the variables that are set in your php.ini.  Either way your problem is deep in your app and not something easily advised.

Comment: @Geoffrey do you know what command could potentially do this from inside my app?  If I knew the name I could search for it to see if it exists anywhere.

Comment: @genadirnik i would look at the functions on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php or anything involving an ini_set

Comment: @Geoffrey Do you think it could have anything to do with session_start() - I use that a lot throughout the application.  Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @Genadinik 7200 is more than likely the culprit because that means 2 hours, something something somewhere is resetting your time from what you have set in your php.ini file.  php_info();exit; could help (displays all the loaded INI values)

Comment: @Geoffrey here is the phpinfo data http://comehike.com/info.php as you can see the session values are much larger.  This is very strange.  I am not doing anything in the code to change it :(

Comment: @Genadinik there must be if your session time is printing out to 7200.  It is just gonna take some deep searching!  Visibility into session is very poor, just keep with it and you will find it.  Trace from start to finish just printing out ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime") until you find the place that the output number changes from 86400 to 7200

Comment: How and where is the session being initialized?  Are you sure it's not using cookie variables instead of session variables?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can increase the session time out using code similar to the below: (in .htaccess, if you are on apache)

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
php_value session.gc_probability 1
php_value session.gc_divisor 100
```

The problem is that your sessions folder can become cluttered with inactive session files. Our sites use a half hour time out, but we have a an AJAX poller as part of the management interface which keeps the session alive once every 15 minutes. That way we only keep the session open for active users (even if they are perfoming long term operations)

Alternatively you may consider storing a separate - longer term - cookie which can be used to quickly re-establish the users session should it expire, again this prevents the need to fill your server with cumbersome session files.